# Properly reach Google Cloud SQL via proxy on Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, bitbucket-pipelines

Whats the proper way to proxy a Cloud SQL Database into Bitbucket Pipelines?

I have a Google Cloud SQL Postgres Instance (And also tried a MySQL DB).

Opening all ports to connections allows bitbucket pipelines to properly deploy my Django based Google App Engine Project, based off this example pipeline - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-bitbucket/blob/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml

However, when I try to limit the access to the Cloud SQL instances and use cloud_sql_proxy instead, I can properly deploy locally, but Bitbucket will always fail to find the SQL Server

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks something like this:

```
        - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
        # Google Cloud SDK is pinned for build reliability. Bump if the SDK complains about deprecation.
        - SDK_VERSION=127.0.0
        - SDK_FILENAME=google-cloud-sdk-${SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
        - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${SDK_FILENAME}
        - tar -zxvf ${SDK_FILENAME} --directory ${HOME}
        - export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
        # Install Google App Engine SDK
        - GAE_PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/google_appengine
        - export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
        - python scripts/fetch_gae_sdk.py $(dirname "${GAE_PYTHONPATH}")
        - echo "${PYTHONPATH}" && ls ${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
        # Install app & dev dependencies, test, deploy, test deployment
        - echo "key = '${GOOGLE_API_KEY}'" > api_key.py
        - echo ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET} > client-secret.json
        - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
        - wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
        - chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
        - ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=google-cloud-project-name:us-west1:google-cloud-sql-database-name=tcp:5432 &
        - gcloud app deploy --no-promote --project google-cloud-project-name --quiet
```

At this point, I would expect to be able to access the SQL database, but it doesn't seem to be available, and my deployment fails to find a local proxy'ed database

Comment: Do you have any logs from the proxy? Try specified the credentials file -credential_file flag. I believe "auth activate-service-account" doesn't affect "application default" credentials which is what the proxy uses if no credential file is specified.

Comment: Does the trick!

Comment: More specifically, the fix is to add `-credential_file=client-secret.json` parameter to `./cloud_sql_proxy`